# Find nearby BLE tags

Tags: javascript, browser, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I need to find nearby BLE tags (them device addresses). It's a simple goal on android. Code to resolve this one looks something like this:

```
bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);

leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 Log.d("test", "getAddress=" + device.getAddress());
             }
         });
     }
};
```

But I can't find solution for browser (JavaScript).

[WebBluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) doesn't support scanning.

Also I saw chrome.bluetooth API for Chrome Apps. Quote from [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth#low-energy):

> As with traditional Bluetooth devices, LE peripherals can be
>   discovered using the methods described in Discovering nearby devices.

But it also doesn't work.

How to find nearby BLE tags from browser? Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome extensions will only work within the Chrome browser, but this is a possibility.

Comment: github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/issues/448 I think it's not possible.